# What are there so many Ubuntu 14.04 LTS AWS AMIs for the same release?

Tags: 14.04, amazon-ec2, aws

A bit of background.  I want to set up a 64-bit AWS EC2 instance running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (HVM) on a solid-state disk with EBS in the eu-west-1 region.

At time of writing, within the AWS control panel quick start I'm offered `Ubuntu Server 14.04 LTS (HVM), SSD Volume Type - ami-f95ef58a`.

A search for `ami-f95ef58a` in the AWS Community AMIs shows this image to be `ubuntu/images/hvm-ssd/ubuntu-trusty-14.04-amd64-server-20160114.5 - ami-f95ef58a`.  So it appears this is a AMI released on 14 Jan 2016.

However, if I search http://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/locator/ec2/ website and use the select boxes to narrow down my choice for my requirements I'm shown:

```
eu-west-1   trusty  14.04 LTS   amd64   hvm:ebs-ssd 20160314    ami-58cc762b    hvm
```

I'm assuming the later release (`ami-58cc762b`) would be a better choice than the one offered in the quick setup.

Which leads me to the point of why are there so many releases of 14.04 LTS?  Surely, the LTS doesn't change so wouldn't it just be better to have a fixed static AMI and update it when it boots.

Are the AMI instances constantly being produced to include patches and updates so the admin won't have to modify the base install?

If so, why doesn't AWS offer the most recent AMI in the quickset and instead offers a AMI that's two months out of date?

Answer (score 0):

AMIs are static images and cannot be changed. Even if they could be updated, they **shouldn't** be (at least not the public AMIs).

The reason for this is that automated deployments rely on precisely-known infrastructure and environments. Suppose I have a piece of code that is dependent on some library that is pre-installed on the AMI, and I know that that code works with the current AMI. If I create a CloudForamtion template to launch an instance with that AMI id and run that piece of code then it should *always* work. **Forever**.

However, if the AMI was allowed to be "updated" and that update causes the library to be changed, then my code may **or may not** be compatible with the latest version of the library, potentially causing the code to fail. It doesn't matter if the library update was done with good intentions (i.e. a bug fix); it needs to be the decision of the **application writer** to update the AMI, and not the AMI maintainer.

If you are using something like CloudFormation to manage your environment, then the AMI ids will be stored in your templates (ideally version controlled!) and updated if and when you are ready to test a new version. Compatibility with a new AMI should be tested just as thoroughly as you would any new feature.